# VBA Macro to format excel report needs performance improvement

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have a VBA macro which inserts a blank line to an excel whenever level column value in current row is not a consecutive number to the level value in previous row, another condition I use is if level in two consecutive rows is same then skip inserting blank line. It works well to format my excel report but for a report with 4,50,000 (0.45 million) rows it takes around 18 mins to complete which is definitely a performance hit.

My VBA Code is

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim r As Range

a = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'MsgBox a

For i = a To 6 Step -1

    'MsgBox i

    x = Cells(i, "A").Value - Cells(i - 1, "A").Value

   ' MsgBox x

    If Not (x = 0) And Not (x = 1) Then

    Rows(i).Resize(1).Insert

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

I can not make much use of external scripts or manual solutions as I need to offer a formatted report as a final output without any post processing steps. Hence trying to achieve this using a macro.

Any suggestions to improve this performance will be really helpful.

[image: Sample Input]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Using an array to transform data and write output to sheet all at once will imporve efficiency
  **Note:** please backup your file before testing.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, lastRow As Long, ColCnt As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = Range("A7:F" & lastRow).Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) * 2, 1 To ColCnt)
    r = 1
    For j = 1 To ColCnt
        arrRes(r, j) = arrData(1, j)
    Next j
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1) Or arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1) + 1 Then
            r = r + 1
        Else
            r = r + 2
        End If
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            arrRes(r, j) = arrData(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("A7").Resize(r, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you efforts. When I try to test this it gives Out of Memory error. I tried using LBOUND, UBOUD and array in simpler manner but it adds additional blank lines even where not required. :(

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `in simpler manner`. I have test the code with 500K rows w/o any issures.

Comment: Simple manner means I am just using a for loop like this:                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                      
vArr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7" & ":" & "A" & a).Value
For i = LBound(vArr) + 4 To UBound(vArr)
    x = vArr(i, 1) - vArr(i - 1, 1)

    If Not (x = 0) And Not (x = 1) Then
    Rows(i).Resize(1).Insert
    End If
Next

Comment: Sorry I had run your code for wrong data; I used your code now, it is just following first condition from OR statement (arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1) Or arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1) + 1) i.e. not inserting line when level values are same; at all other rows a new line is inserted.

Comment: Are you not facing such issue?

Comment: No, It is clearly that `arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1)` is for the same leve.

Comment: Thanks @taller for this answer, with a little addition to your answer I am able to achieve very good performance.

Comment: But you said you tested with 500K rows without any issues. I am not able to run this for 40K rows. There are no errors showing up but code just does not insert blank lines if rows are more than 10K.

Comment: I tried to debug the issue for a week now but not able to understand why macro is not able to take more than 10K rows. How can I add my modified code again here?

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: Thanks. I have created follow up question and shared macro in there; - <https://stackoverflow.com/q/78131294/22768530>