# Format excel report needs performance improvement

Tags: excel, vba

This is follow up question for another question- [VBA Macro to format excel report needs performance improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77615561/22768530)

I have a VBA macro which inserts a blank line to an excel whenever level column value in current row is not a consecutive number to the level value in previous row, another condition I use is if level in two consecutive rows is same then skip inserting blank line.
Using the answer to that question I just added few lines and it had given perfect performance, but that code works only for 10K rows and if rows > 10K it does nothing, no error as well. I think it just gets data but does not paste transformed data. I have been debugging this from couple of days but not able to make it work. Any hint/help will be really appreciated. Below is the vba I am using:

````
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CarryOn = MsgBox("Do you want to run a macro that will format the report?", vbYesNo, "Report Formatting Automation")
    If CarryOn = vbYes Then
     'Backup report
    Sheets("Where Used Report").Copy after:=Sheets("Where Used Report")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Original Where Used Report"
    Sheets("Where Used Report").Activate

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, lastRow, ColCnt As Long
    Dim a, b, c As Long
    Dim numCheck
    
    'macro on open file event
    If Cells(1, 4).Value = "1" Then
    'do not run open macro if already run once
    Else
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = Range("A6:S" & lastRow).Value
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) * 2, 1 To ColCnt)
    r = 1
    For j = 1 To ColCnt
        arrRes(r, j) = arrData(1, j)
    Next j
    MsgBox LBound(arrData)
    MsgBox UBound(arrData)
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
    a = arrData(i, 1)
    b = arrData(i - 1, 1)
    
    numCheck = IsNumeric(b)
    
    If numCheck = True Then
    c = arrData(i - 1, 1) + 1
    Else
   'No where used component
   GoTo Last
   End If
        If a = b Or a = c Then
           'MsgBox "No line break"
            r = r + 1
        Else
            'MsgBox "Need a line break"
            r = r + 2
        End If
        
        For j = 1 To ColCnt
            arrRes(r, j) = arrData(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
        'MsgBox "Copy start"
        Range("C5:C" & r).NumberFormat = "0000"
        Range("A6").Resize(r, ColCnt).Value = arrRes
        'MsgBox "Copy Complete"
        Cells(1, 4).Value = "1"  
   End If   
   Else
   ' MsgBox ("Report format is to be kept same."
End If
Last:
Cells(1, 4).Value = "1"
End Sub```
````

Comment: What the result of `MsgBox UBound(arrData)`? Is it correct to get the last row#? `if rows > 10K it does nothing` Does it means the table isn't change after code execution? If so, it means there is a non-numeric cell ( row number is greater than 10K ).

Comment: Add msgbox before goto clause ( `MsgBox i-1 : GoTo Last` ) to check which cell is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If a cell contains non-numeric content, the code will proceed to the `Last:` section, and the table update code will be skipped.

---

- If you opt for using `Goto`, ensure you include an `Exit Sub` before `Last:`. Without it, regardless of whether `numCheck` is True or False, the `Last:` section will be executed.
- Adding code to update cell `D1` with different values can be useful for identifying issues with the data.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' ...
                If numCheck = True Then
                    c = arrData(i - 1, 1) + 1
                Else
                    'No where used component
                    GoTo Last
                End If
                ' ...
    Else
        ' MsgBox ("Report format is to be kept same."
    End If
    Exit Sub
Last:
    Cells(1, 4).Value = "Error on row" & i-1
End Sub
```

---

- I would recommend avoiding the use of `Goto`, as illustrated below.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' ...
                If numCheck = True Then
                    c = arrData(i - 1, 1) + 1
                Else
                    'No where used component
                    Cells(1, 4).Value = "Error on row" & i-1
                    Exit Sub
                End If
   '...
    Else
        ' MsgBox ("Report format is to be kept same."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, value in a cell was non numeric post 10K lines because of the data and I have eliminated use of Goto as you sugested in last section. This gave me correct idea of where to find the defective lines. I used this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### 'Insert' Empty Rows Efficiently

The cells in range `"A6:D6,D7:D22,A23:D23"` are assumed to be empty (`CurrentRegion` related).

[image]

**Usage**

```vb
Sub InsertEmptyRowsTEST()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_TABLE_CELL As String = "A7"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const EMPTY_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 1
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With ws.Range(FIRST_TABLE_CELL).CurrentRegion
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    ' Insert empty rows.
    InsertEmptyRows srg, CRITERIA_COLUMN, EMPTY_ROWS_COUNT
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Empty rows inserted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Inserts empty row(s) between each row of a range,
'               where in a given column containing integers, the difference
'               between the current and the previous row's value IS NOT 0 OR 1.
' Remarks:      The solution requires the cells adjacent to the right
'               of the range to be empty.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub InsertEmptyRows( _
        ByVal sourceRange As Range, _
        ByVal CriteriaColumn As Long, _
        Optional ByVal EmptyRowsCount As Long = 1)
    
    Dim sData() As Variant, srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    With sourceRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count
        If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' just one row
        scCount = .Columns.Count
        If scCount < CriteriaColumn Then Exit Sub
        sData = .Columns(CriteriaColumn).Value
    End With
    
    Dim drData() As Long:
    ReDim drData(1 To (EmptyRowsCount + 1) * srCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = scCount + 1
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, er As Long, IsFirstFound As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        dr = dr + 1
        If IsFirstFound Then
            Select Case sData(sr, 1) - sData(sr - 1, 1)
            Case 0, 1
            Case Else
                For er = 1 To EmptyRowsCount
                    drCount = drCount + 1
                    drData(drCount, 1) = dr
                    dr = dr + 1
                Next er
            End Select
            drData(sr, 1) = dr
        Else ' first row
            drData(1, 1) = 1
            IsFirstFound = True
        End If
    Next sr
            
    Dim derg As Range: Set derg = sourceRange.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = derg.Columns(dcCount)
    
    Dim ScreenUpdatingStatus As Boolean:
    ScreenUpdatingStatus = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    dcrg.Value = drData
    derg.Sort dcrg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    dcrg.ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdatingStatus

End Sub
```